# Decrease line height for usernames on review stats page

Tags: feature-request, design, review-stats

Another minor CSS issue: on the [review stats page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats), long usernames are being wrapped (which is fine) but take up too much vertical space (which is not fine). When the space between those lines is decreased, it should take up space no more than the avatars, leading to the original situation where all rows had the same height.

[image]