# User name in review queue statistics is overflowing

Tags: bug, review, design

I am viewing the review queue stats for Drones.SE and my name seems to overflow the text box:

[image]

This seems to happen to everyone who is the first reviewer for that queue on all SE sites.

ELL stats:

[image]

Info:

- iOS 13.4.1
- Firefox 25.1

Comment: Related: [Decrease line height for usernames on review stats page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344848/295232) (as in: if they fix this bug, they could have a look at my proposal as well)]